# Using jquery to select an element by it's style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select an html element that has no classes or id's, but I still need to select it. Here is what the element looks like:

```
    <table style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left: 10px solid 
    #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;" class="">
```

I tried to make a selector that got the element like this:

```
    $("table[style~='background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-left: 10px solid 
    #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;']")
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: you can't select an element by it's style attributes in jquery. do you have any parent elements you can target?

Comment: There's some missing whitespace in your selector in the `rgba` function. I'd suggest adding that and seeing if it works.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that you couldn't select an element based on it's css. I'll try to find a parent element that I can select.

Comment: Of course you can, that statement is wrong. jQuery accepts any CSS syntax, and using `style` is an attribute selector.

Comment: You could use `filter()` to select an element by it's CSS attributes, but it's not really a great idea to do so. Why do you need this? Can you not select the element by it's ancestors, eg `#container .foo > .bar table`?

Comment: Modify your style and suddenly your js doesn't work... please avoid this completely. Find another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is just wrong, you are missing some spaces.

You can use the [**attribute selector**](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) in jQuery for `style` but have in mind that an inline-style can change **if another javascript function affects the element style the selector will not work**.

---

**Looking for another selector is much better**, look for a class or an id wrapping the table element.

If there is, do something like this:

```
.el table {}
OR
#el table {}
```

---

Using Attribute selector:

```js
console.log($('table[style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left: 10px solid #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left: 10px solid #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;"></table>
```

---

Using [**filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```js
console.log($('table').filter('[style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left: 10px solid #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left: 10px solid #1E90FF; margin: 0 auto;"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the substring select `*=`, and only matching against a unique portion of the style attribute:

```
$("table[style*='background-color: white; border: 1px solid #aaa;']")
```

Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div[style^="background: blue; "]').append('<p>This is the selected</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: red; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;"></div>
<div style="background: blue; color: #fff; height: 500px; border: 2px solid green;"></div>
```